# How to use session timeout in django rest view?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, session-timeout

I am implementing a view for a game using Django REST's APIView. I am very new to Django and have never done this before so I'm not sure how to implement this.

The main idea is that a game only lasts 5 minutes. I am sending a resource to the user and creating a session object. This view. should be unavailable after 5 minutes. Is there such a thing as a view timeout?

Will the session timeout then work for the post request as well or do I need to implement it there as well?

This is my view:

The out commented code at the end is what I was thinking of doing. Can I even do it in the view directly? How else can I do this and test it?

**views.py**

```
class GameView(APIView):
    """
    API View that retrieves the game,
    retrieves an game round as well as a random resource per round
    allows users to post tags that are verified and saved accordingly to either the Tag or Tagging table
    """

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        current_score = 0
        if not isinstance(request.user, CustomUser):
            current_user_id = 1
        else:
            current_user_id = request.user.pk

        random_resource = Resource.objects.all().order_by('?').first()
        resource_serializer = ResourceSerializer(random_resource)

        gameround = Gameround.objects.create(user_id=current_user_id,
                                             gamesession=gamesession,
                                             created=datetime.now(),
                                             score=current_score)

        gameround_serializer = GameroundSerializer(gameround)

        return Response({'resource': resource_serializer.data,
            'gameround': gameround_serializer.data,
        })
        # TODO: handle timeout after 5 min!
        # now = timezone.now()
        # end_of_game = start_time + timezone.timedelta(minutes=5)
        # if :
        # return Response({'resource': resource_serializer.data, 'gameround': gameround_serializer.data,})
        # else:
        # return Response(status=status.HTTP_408_REQUEST_TIMEOUT)
```

*Testing the out commented code in Postman always leads to a 408_request_timeout.

Comment: You can do the timeout in the HTML using JS . The  request cannot be alive for five minutes.

Comment: But is there a way to do it here as well? I am doing the backend only and have to implement it somehow ... Is there a way of doing it inside the view or otherwise?

Comment: you could use django PasswordResetTokenGenerator to generate a token with a timeout of 5mn. This token would be used to validate if a user has access to some resource.

Comment: Can I input this in the view directly?